# CDK2 Using existing KinesisFirehose Resource

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create a Kinesis Firehose Delivery stream and the current Alpha version (L2 Constructs) doesn't support format conversion. (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15501)

I am trying to create the Delivery Stream using L2 Construct and then use L1 Construct(CfnDeliveryStream) to do a lookup and add the required changes.

How ever there is not fromResourceName() or fromResourceARN() methods available.

What options do we have now instead of creating the Firehouse using L1 construct.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any lookups. You can access the L1 resource directly with [`myDeliveryStream.node.defaultChild`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#defaultchild)

Comment: Thanks a lot gshpychka, that should address the issue. In typescript it seems straightforward (as I am more familiar with it. Trying to see how to type cast in python)

Comment: use typing.cast()